# How to revert to 16.04LTS

Tags: system-installation

I had 16.04LTS version installed on by laptop along side the windows 10. I upgraded to 17.04 version but it did not install properly and now I cannot open Ubuntu on the computer but can access windows...

How can I revert back to previous version that is 16.04 LTS version

Comment: There is no way to revert. You will need to do a fresh install.

Comment: Can I get my data created in ubuntu using windows 10

Comment: You can boot form a Live USB and get all data. You can also do an install preserving the data.